# Entity Framework 6.20, keep having to change System.Data.Objects to System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm using the Entity Framework 6.20 with c#, Visual Studio 2017.

Whenever I update my object model from the database in my Model.Context.cs my lines:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses;
```

automatically change to

```
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
```

then I get many errors saying:

The type or namespace name 'Objects' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

So I just need to change the two lines back to how they were, but why is this happening? Can I stop it happening?

Thanks - Ben

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is because your .tt are outdated or you have had a update/migration from one entity framework version to another

The Model.Context.cs is automatically generated, so you can edit it you Model.Context.tt (this is a T4 template used to generated code automatically)

in solution explorer open the file Model.Context.tt 
Then search the using lines that given you the errors , modify with the correct values and save the file, later right clik over this file and select Run Custom Tool.

I'll hope that this will be the solution, regards